# Como pego dois números digitados pelo usuário via formulário e envio para uma função que vai pegar um valor aleatório entre eles no React

Tags: javascript, html, funções, react, formulário

No momento meu código esta assim, mas está muito bagunçado, embora creio que seja possível entender a intenção.

A questão é: Como pego dois números digitados pelo usuário via formulário e envio para uma função que vai pegar um valor aleatório entre eles no React?

```js
import React from 'react';
import '../styles/pagescss/aleatorio.css';

function Aleatorio() {

  function refreshPage() {
    window.location.reload(false);
  }

  function declararVariavel() {
    var max = document.getElementById('max').value;
    var min = document.getElementById('min').value;
  }

  function getRandomInt(max, min) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
  }

  const Numeros = () => {
    return getRandomInt();
  };

  return (
    <div id="corpo">

      <h2 id="titulo">JavaScript Math Random</h2>

      <p id="texto">A expressão: <br /> Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min <br />retorna um numero inteiro aleatorio</p>

      <form id="form">
        <label id="label">
          <input type="number" id="max" placeholder="Máximo" />
          <input type="number" id="min" placeholder="Mínimo" />
        </label>

        <input onclick="declararVariavel()" type="submit" id="botao" placeholder="Enviar" />
      </form>



      <div id="botao">
        <button onClick={refreshPage}>Gerar Números</button>
      </div>

      <div id="numeroCorpo">
        <div id="number">
          <Numeros />
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  );


}

export default Aleatorio;
```

quero pegar a informação digitada nos dois inputs (`min` e `max`) e colocar na função `getRandomInt()`

Comment: Observou a resposta?

Answer (score 0):

Eu não sei aonde está aprendendo [react](/questions/tagged/react), porque, está fazendo tudo errado, usando comandos que não deve usar e não utilizando os recursos de estado do componente local, exemplo mínimo para solução do seu problema:

```js
function Aleatorio(){
  const [min, setMin] = React.useState(0);
  const [max, setMax] = React.useState(0);
  const [ale, setAle] = React.useState(0);
  function handleSubmit(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    setAle(getRandomInt(max, min));            
  }
  function getRandomInt(max, min) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
  }
  const Numeros = () => {
    return (
      <div className="mt-3 text-center">
        <h1>{ale}</h1>
      </div>
    )  
  };  
  return (
    <div className="container">
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <div className="row">
        <div className="col-6">
          <div className="form-group">
          <label>Min: </label>          
          <input 
            className="form-control"
            type="number" 
            value={min} 
            onChange={e => setMin(parseInt(e.target.value))}
           />
           </div>
        </div>
        <div className="col-6">
          <div className="form-group">
          <label>Max:</label>          
          <input
            className="form-control"
            type="number" 
            value={max} 
            onChange={e => setMax(parseInt(e.target.value))}
          />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="col-12 mt-3">
          <button type="submit" 
            class="btn btn-primary btn-block"
            disabled={isNaN(min) || isNaN(max) || (max === min) || (min > max)}
          >
            Gerar Números
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
      </form>
      <Numeros />
    </div>
  )
}


ReactDOM.render( <Aleatorio/> , document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.9.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.9.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root">Carregando ...</div>
```

nessa solução foi criado 3 variáveis de estado que fazem parte desse componente, guardaram `min`, `max` e `ale` (valor mínimo, valor máximo e valor aleatório) onde vão ser ligados as alterações de seus respectivos `<input/>` onde no momento da digitação os valores também serão alterados.

Ao pressionar o botão com etiqueta ***Gerar Números*** o formulário é submetido e interceptado para não acontecer o evento comum de submissão do formulário e após esse comando, gerar o valor aleatório para a variável `ale`.

Tudo isso foi utilizado somente comandos da `library` [react](/questions/tagged/react) e tem muito material na Internet que possa te ajudar, por exemplo:

- [React - Uma biblioteca JavaScript para criar interfaces de usuário](https://pt-br.reactjs.org/)
- [React - Onde Obter Suporte](https://pt-br.reactjs.org/community/support.html)
- [React - Blog](https://pt-br.reactjs.org/blog/2020/10/20/react-v17.html)
- [Rocketseat - Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCSfwM5u0Kce6Cce8_S72olg)